# How to determine and set the correct python unicode format

Tags: unicode, pickle, python-unicode

I run the following lines of code using python 3.9 and receive the error message "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pickle

fName = 'fileName.pkl'
with open(fName, 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
```

How do I know what the correct encoding format is? What are the different encoding formats?

Comment: [`pickle.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) uses default `encoding='ASCII'`. I'd try `encoding='utf-8'` or `encoding='cp1252'`, see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Note that the `#coding` comment declares the encoding of the *source file* and nothing to do with `pickle`.  UTF-8 is also the default encoding for Python 3 source files so the comment is redundant as well.

Comment: Without some knowledge of how the .pkl file was generated, we can only guess, but see the optional argument guidance in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler). Was it generated by Python2?